# Importing specific row data using conditional formatting from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I would like to accomplish if possible using conditional formatting formulas –

Scan an asset tag number into a column to quickly pull just that specific asset’s information by the unique asset #

– i.e

I scanned the asset “ASST123456789” into A4 of sheet “Asset info”

And I would like to automatically import the asset information from another sheet , in this example from “Inventory Database CSV.  and populate columns B1,C4,D4,E4 and F4

This way I don’t have to CTRL-F as it can get a bit glitchy trying to sift through the huge inventory sheet just to query a single device for a serial number or whatever cell data I need from the row the asset is in.

[query sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2Dk4.png)

[inventory sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncxrV.png)

Comment: Have you tried using vLookup?
What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vlookup. enter this formula `=VLOOKUP($A4,'Inventory Database CSV'!$A$2:$F$50000,COLUMN(Sheet1!B$4),FALSE)` in cell `B4` and drag it to right and down across your Asset Info sheet.